# Where I should ask career guidance questions.?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask question like how should I choose a career and when, what kind of education I should take to become a project manager or a software engineer.?

Comment: From Programmers.Meta: [Why was my question closed as off topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980) and [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980).  Note that chat is a good place to ask (stop by the chat room for either Workplace.SE or Programmers.SE some time and ask there).  I also have a section "Where else can discussions be had?"

Answer (score 7):

As a [moderator on a site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) which frequently gets these sorts of questions, which are off-topic, thank you for asking here first rather than trying to guess. It's VERY appreciated.

> Where can I ask question like how should I choose a career and when, what kind of education I should take to become a project manager or a software engineer.?

There really are no sites on the Stack Exchange network a question like this is appropriate.

Perhaps some chat environments might be receptive to this, but both [Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168) and [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980) would close questions like this quickly as they are not on-topic on either.

Answer (score 6):

> how should I choose a career and when, what kind of education I should take...

Before anyone jumps in with a misguided advice about Workplace.SE, I would like to point out that questions like this would fit their [custom close reason](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168):

> > Questions asking for **advice on what to do are not [practical answerable questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)** (e.g. *"what job should I take?"*, or *"what skills should I learn?"*). Questions should get answers explaining *why* and *how* to make a decision, not advice on what to do. For more information, click [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695).

Our goal here at The Workplace is to help out people in the future who are facing the same problem. When people ask us for personalized advice, a lot of the specific details will not apply to other people who come across the question since their details may be slightly different and they can't determine whether or not the answer is appropriate for their situation.

> 

Questions about what decision to make are best asked to your friends and family, or maybe Facebook. You can always try asking in our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) where the rules are quite a bit more relaxed. Sometimes talking through a decision can help, so it's best to pick a format designed for that sort of back-and-forth discussion. The Workplace is [not that place though](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour).

> 

Another alternative is to [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your post to ask about *why* and *how* you should make the decision, rather than just *what* decision to make. For instance, instead of asking *"Should I take the job in the big multi-national company or the up-and-coming startup?"* you could ask a question that will help you make that decision, like *"How can I figure out the financial health of a startup I am applying to by asking questions in an interview?"*

Answer (score 0):

Stackexchange is for questions with a single answer. Quora is for open-ended responses.

I'm not meaning to be dismissive, but the truth is that if you are looking for advice on an open-ended this isn't the right "forum." (Quotes because we are not a forum!). It really is that simple.